# What happens when a SQL query runs out of memory?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I want to set up a Postgres server on AWS, the biggest table will be 10GB - do I have to select 10GB of memory for this instance?

What happens when my query result is larger than 10GB?

Comment: It gives you `out of memory` error.

Comment: @Asdfg does your comment imply the complete result set must always fit into ram? (I highly doubt it)

Comment: I assume it is RDS instance where resources are shared so I highly doubt it will let you burst the memory.

Comment: @Asdfg that's right. But my point is: whether postgresql strictly must allocate for the whole result set. Cannot it just read through a buffer of a limited size?

Comment: No, you can run a 10GB db on a tiny device without any problems.

Comment: @jarlh: its not about running a 10GB db. Its about the query's result size.

Comment: @Asdfg Where are you getting that the result set is stored entirely in memory?  The only factor that should matter is if a single operation actually requires more memory than the max available.

Comment: I have an x*10GB postgres database running on a Raspberry Pi-1 with *only* 512MB of memory. Works like a charm. The point is: keeping work_mem and connected clients low enough+proper indexing.

Comment: It depends a lot on **how** you execute the query. Worst case, yes, you’ll load the entire results into memory, and you will run out of memory. Best case, you read and process the data row by row, and only need a limited amount of memory. Server side, it depends on the query. Some will see data returned as it is read from disk and will require little memory. Others will require intermediary processing (sorts, hashes, etc.) and will potentially use a lot of memory, spilling out to disk beyond limits. Optimised requests that make good use of indexes are the way to go.

Comment: Looks like your edit invalidated a few of the answers, I've restored the previous revision now. Do edit the post to incorporate suggestions and enhance the present post, but don't edit to drastically change the topic of the question at hand. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will happen, the entire result set is not loaded into memory.  The maximum available memory will be used and re-used as needed while the result is prepared and will spill over to disk as needed.

See PostgreSQL [resource documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-resource.html) for more info.

Specifically, look at `work_mem`:

> **work_mem** (integer)
>   Specifies the amount of memory to be used by internal sort operations and hash tables before writing to temporary disk files.

As long as you don't run out of working memory on a single operation or set of parallel operations you are fine.

**Edit:** The above was an answer to the question `What happens when you query a 10GB table without 10GB of memory on the server/instance?`

Here is an updated answer to the updated question:

- Only server side resources are used to produce the result set
- Assuming JDBC drivers are used, by default, the entire result set is sent to your local computer which could cause out of memory errors

This behavior can be changed by altering the fetch size through the use of a cursor.

[Reference to this behavior here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/queries-troubleshooting.html)

[Getting results based on a cursor](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor)

Comment: Even though I personally also agree with it - the community would win if some evidence was provided.

Comment: @zerkms It's actually hard to find this explicitly stated, but I added what I could for sourcing.  It's just basic memory management functionality.

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, with a simple query like yours it just keeps a "cursor" which points to where it's at, as it's spooling the results to you, and uses very little memory.  Now if there were some "sorts" in there or what not, that didn't have indexes it could use, that might use up lots of memory, not sure there.  On the client side the postgres JDBC client by default loads the "entire results" into memory before passing them back to you (overcomeable by specifying a fetch count).

With more complex queries  (for example give me all 100M rows, but order them by "X" where X is not indexed) I don't know, but probably internally it creates a temp table (so it won't run out of RAM) which, treated as a normal table, uses disk backing.  If there's a matching index then it can just traverse that, using a pointer, still uses little RAM.

Answer (score -1):

Identifying large memory objects associated with MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL may make this situation on November 18 more clear.

```
-- memory objects in MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL
SELECT omo.type, omo.pages_in_bytes, omo.partition_type_desc, 
omo.memory_node_id
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_objects omo
JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_clerks omc 
ON omo.page_allocator_address = omc.page_allocator_address
WHERE omc.type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL'
ORDER BY pages_in_bytes DESC;
```

Comment: You might have _answered_ on the wrong question?